# Oracle - Listing Orders by Date

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to list the orders; however, it keeps saying date is invalid. I learned how to enter the correct date format; however, I cannot seem to have it retrieved.

```
SELECT ORDER_NUM, ORDERS.CUSTOMER_NUM, CUSTOMER_NAME
  FROM ORDERS, CUSTOMER
 WHERE     ORDERS.CUSTOMER_NUM = CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NUM
       AND ORDER_DATE = '23-10-2010'; <------ INVALID
```

Comment: Maybe you need the `TO_DATE` function?

Answer (score 2):

```
AND ORDER_DATE = to_date( '23-10-2010', 'DD-MM-YYYY' );
```

or

```
AND ORDER_DATE = DATE '2010-10-23';
```

Answer (score 1):

You entered a varchar2 instead of a date in the condition.

In order to convert your varchar2 into Date, you must use TO_DATE function.

```
ORDER_DATE = TO_DATE('23-10-2010', 'DD-MM-YYYY');
```

You can read more about the TO_DATE function here:

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php